# How to calculate the mean of null values in pandas?

Tags: pandas

```
ser = pd.Series([1,2,np.nan,4,np.nan])
ser.fillna(ser.mean())
```

Output:

> 1.000000
> 2.000000
> 2.333333 (how it is 2.33, it was null value)
> 4.000000
> 2.333333

Comment: its not very clear what you're expecting. Please add the expected output for expected solutions

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing there is filling your blank values, with the average of those numbers. So when previously null, it is afterwards imputed with the average of the series.

Using your `series` and calling `mean()` on it gives back 2.333 (calculated us (1+2+4) / 3 as `np.nan` are ignored):

```
ser = pd.Series([1,2,np.nan,4,np.nan])
>>> ser.mean()
2.3333333333333335
```

And calling again your series:

```
>>> ser

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    4.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

However, when you add `fillna()` in your series, and give as a parameter your `ser.mean()`, i.e it's average, it fill the nulls with the average shown above:

```
>>> ser.fillna(ser.mean())

0    1.000000
1    2.000000
2    2.333333
3    4.000000
4    2.333333
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.nan` are not counted as 0, they are ignored.

You may do :

`ser.fillna(ser.fillna(0).mean())`

**Ouput:**

| 0 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1.4 |
| 4 |
| 1.4 |